# QTreeWidget created at runtime failed to emit itemDoubleClicked signal

Tags: pyqt, qtreewidget

I made a widget that inherits from QTreeWidget and successfully created an instance and added it to a tab control. However, I am trying to capture the itemDoubleClicked signal, but failed. I tried to put the connect statement in either the form that has the tab control, it failed to emit signal, then I put the connect inside my custom widget, it failed also. So, not sure how to connect to a tree widget that is created at runtime.

from within my custom QTreeWidget class:
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL('itemDoubleClicked(QTreeWidgetItem, int)'), self.edit_treeitem)

or from within the tab control:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.mytree, QtCore.SIGNAL('itemDoubleClicked(QTreeWidgetItem, int)'), self.edit_treeitem)
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the new style of signal connection:

```
self.mytree.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.edit_treeitem)
```

Comment: Thanks! that does it. I am just frustrated in that every documentation says the QtCore.QObject.connect is the way to connect to this signal, and I was under the impression that is the 'new' way, but apparently this works... really hope you can explain why... anyway, thnx

Comment: @ForComment unfortunately a lot of tutorials etc. are out of date. The `QObject.connect` way is the old way and seems to be quite picky and people often have trouble making it work. I suspect something was wrong with the string that defines the signal in your original code but stopped trying to debug these long ago! It's just easier to switch to the new style. See [PyQt Docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) for details of the new system.